# Select first child of a particular element with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the first child element (doesn't matter what type of element it is) of a particular element, and this is what I have:

```xml
//main[@id='main2']/*[first()]
```

I've also tried:

```xml
//main[@id='main2']/*[1]
```

Both are returning null, and I know the first child is not null, so I'm just wondering what's wrong with the expression and/or how I would go about getting the first child of the `//main[@id='main2']` element. I've tried Googling for some time, but to no avail.

Comment: First child or first sibling? You mention both in your question. A small example of your XML would be super helpful.

Comment: Also what context are you doing this in? How did you account for namespaces?

Comment: @DanielHaley The first child, I edited the question. I wanted the first child of the main tag with an id of main2

Comment: Your second attempt should work. Example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93whGpL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `first()` XPath function; use `[1]` instead, as you do in your second XPath.  (There is, however, a `last()` function.)

This XPath,

```
//main[@id='main2']/*[1]
```

selects the first ***element*** child of the `main2` `main` element.  To select the first ***node*** (element, text, comment, or processing instruction), use the `node()` test rather than `*`:

```
//main[@id='main2']/node()[1]
```

If the first XPath is selecting nothing, then there are no element children of the targeted `main` element.  If you still find your results to be confusing, post your XML so that we can guide you more specifically regarding what you're seeing.

Comment: The errors are occurring elsewhere in my code, but the original answers were returning what was expected.